# GitHub for Windows - I commit and sync, but list of uncommit changes stays

Tags: windows, github, commit

I made my changes and it shows the list of files on the left side.
They are all checked, I enter the commit text and do commit and then I sync.
There is even a progress bar.

But when it's all done, the list of files is still there as if there was no commit. 
There was no error message that I could see. 
On the right side where it says the historic of commit it's there too.

When I got to github.com I do not see these changes. Any idea why?

Comment: unexpected situations with git on windows can happen with: filesystem case (in)sensitivity / line endings (autocrlf) / executable bit. can you elaborate if either might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially silly question (especially given you are using a GUI), but are you sure you are committing from the correct location?

I've fallen victim to the same thing and it happens when I have multiple SSH windows open in and I accidentally try to commit from live (as opposed to dev) after just having pulled. This fails in the same way you describe as live is never ahead of the repo. I've kicked myself for not seeing it quickly before.

Comment: I checked, it's the right folder.
It's a simple setup really, with a single branch.
We have been using it only for about 2 days, maybe a dozen commits.
So we haven't been switching things around at all.

Comment: I decided to take a look with the git GLI.
Did git status, got the same list. I added all those files using git add .     
I figured, since all changes were on that computer, there is no danger of overwriting or conflict.

The result was a bunch of : 
"The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in website/manage-pages-warranty.html."

then I did a git status to see what's going on, no files to commit.

So instead of listing the files I added as ready to commit, the list was clean.  Strange.

Comment: Yeah, the LF / CRLF error can safely be ignored (it's an OS based newline preference (CR, LF, or CRLF)). Have you tried a git pull --rebase?